# How to fix NixOS localtime service?

Tags: timezone, nixos

Setting `services.localtime.enable = true;` [should](https://nixos.org/nixos/options.html#services.localtime.enable) start a "simple daemon for keeping the system timezone up-to-date based on the current location.", but [it doesn't](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/67673):

> Failed to get target of /etc/localtime: No such file or directory

`touch /etc/localtime` might fix it in the short run, but I don't expect that's a reasonable workaround – NixOS' /etc is not meant to be hacked this way, after all. I guess some other setting is also needed to make this work, but the documentation doesn't mention anything. Unfortunately the bug report linked above hasn't received any attention, so I hope someone in this community knows what to do.

---

[Setting `time.timeZone = "UTC";` as well](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/67673#issuecomment-527859105) results in the service starting. However, the service (and the geoclue service) don't produce any useful output:

```
$ journalctl --boot --output=cat --unit geoclue.service
Starting Location Lookup Service...
Started Location Lookup Service.
$ journalctl --boot --output=cat --unit systemd-timedated.service
Starting Time & Date Service...
Started Time & Date Service.
Failed to set timezone: Europe/Zurich
```

and **the /etc/localtime symlink keeps pointing to /etc/zoneinfo/UTC** even after being online for an hour or so.

Comment: The description sounds like it's an issue, i.e. more suitable for https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues - and probably ping @michaelpj there (recently changed some things in the module).

Comment: @VladimírČunát I've already linked [the relevant issue](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/67673), but thanks for the ping hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `services.localtimed.enable = true;` in NixOS 23.05 *does* seem to work as expected:

```
❯ journalctl --boot --output=cat --unit=localtimed
Starting localtimed.service...
Started localtimed.service.
2023/10/09 08:59:12 Updated timezone to: Pacific/Auckland
```